# Can i use jhipster-registry as a discovery server over instances of jhipster v1.9.0 application

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I currently am using version 1.9.0 jhipster. Can i have jhipster registry installed and configured to this or am i looking at this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but you will have to upgrade spring boot in your old apps to a version supported by spring-cloud-netflix and then use `@EnableEurekaClient`.
During this process you will need to resolve all upgrade issues with dependencies you use (JPA, Hibernate, ...) which could be a positive thing anyway.

Without modifying your app, you could use JHipster registry with [Netflix Prana](https://github.com/Netflix/Prana/wiki) as a sidecar Eureka client.

If you don't want to modify your apps, you could rely on other service discovery solutions:

- package your apps as docker containers and use Kubernetes
- or use [HashiCorp Consul](https://www.consul.io/) maybe with DNS forwarding and with consul-template to generate your application.yml files